Can JHove only write its output to file and not make it directly available in the program?
I am trying out JHove for TIFF file validation and learn it writes its output to file
which is a bit cumbersome for our application.
Is it possible that JHove's output is availabe directly within the program? Maybe via
the handler interface against which one can write its own handler to capture the output data?
Thanks!
Jan

After some more researching found the answer in the JHOVE Tips For developers PDF which is a treasure trove of valuable information on JHOVE:
JHOVE’s output can be customized by writing a new output handler or subclassing an existing one. Any handler has to implement the interface edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.OutputHandler, and it can almost always subclass edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.HandlerBase. An output handler doesn’t have to write to a file; it can process the information which the module provides in just about any way, such as transforming it so that the application can continue using it.

Think it would be good to introduce a JHOVE tag for easy searching. To my surprise it doesn't exist, so if anybody with the authorization to create one; Much appreciated!
